# how to call a method from a class in another class

Tags: objective-c

I'm working to a new app for mac osx where i'm using a drag and drop system to let the user to input some files [this part works well] and i have a tabelView where i would like to display the paths of files inputed.
I have the next method in tabelViewController.m:

```
-(void)add{
    NSLog(@"da");
    [list addObject:[[Source alloc] init]];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

In the DropView.m i included the tabelViewController.h and i'm trying to call the add method but it does nothing:

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
.....
- (void)concludeDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    TableViewController *tvc;
    [tvc add];
}
```

Can someone to figure out why it doesn't do anything ?

Edit1:
Ok after I fallow the answers, my concludeDragOperation method looks like this:

```
- (void)concludeDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    TableViewController *tvc = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
    [tvc add];
    [tvc rD];
}
```

rD is a method from tableViewController which contain the reloadData method.
But it doesn't want to work it don't reload the table view.
Any ideea ???

Answer (score 1):

`tvc` needs to point to an actual object. `[[tvc alloc] init]` 
Otherwise you are simply calling add on `nil`. This doesn't cause your program to crash as you might expect in other languages. Try it out and see what happens.

Comment: i see now it does something but not exactly what i want.[i can see that it is working by the NSLogs which i inserted] but the tableview is not update with some values which i defined in data source. but if i use a button [ i made an IBAction add1 which contains the same lines as void add] it works

Answer (score 1):

it seems as if you missed a great chunk regarding how OOP and Objective-C work (seriously, no offense there).

What link is there between DropView.m and tableViewController.h do you have?

By typing `TableViewController *tvc;` all you are doing is creating a pointer. You are neither creating an object nor pointing to an object, you have just simply created a pointer that *can* eventually point to an object in memory of type tableViewController.

**Solution:**

What you will need to do, is to somehow create a link between the two classes. For instance, you could create a custom delegate method for DropView that could communicate with any class who uses that custom DropViewDelegate methods. So, you could create a delegate method that tells objects that follow that delegate protocol that you just concluded a drag operation. A tutorial how to do so can be found at my [blog](http://achim.us/eli/iOS/archives/25) [it's a permalink].

I am happy to post code, or you can read it on my blog. Good Luck.

Comment: I didn't take it as an offence of course I'm quite beginner in oop